# grep a string after pattern match in python

Tags: python

I want to extract the testbed name from a file. This is the line where the name is present, How could I do it in Python?

```
Status: aaa (image='some_image_name' on testbed='test_bed_name' archiving)
```

I was thinking of splitting the string taking the index, but this line may not be the same in all my files. there might be some small changes.

Comment: Downvote: Please demonstrate your own effort so far; without code we can't really tell where you are stuck or how much you already know. Also, with a single sample, it's hard to generalize - multiple sample lines, and/or examples of things we should not include would focus the question significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is always like that, you could simply slice your way to the right place:

```
>>> s.split('=')[-1].split(' ')[0][1:-1]
test_bed_name
```

Or, you can use regular expressions:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:.*?)testbed='(.*?)'(?:.*?)", s)
test_bed_name
```

The above is a bit of a ham-fisted approach to regular expressions, but you can always tweak it out to make it a bit more precise.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting a syntax eror with the regular expression. I'm newbie. Could you please help?

Comment: Have you checked you are using the correct set of `"` ? Check the update, there was a small typo there.

Comment: Solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With a lookbehind.

```
>>> re.search("(?<=testbed=')([^']+)'", "Status: aaa (image='some_image_name' on testbed='test_bed_name' archiving)").groups()
('test_bed_name',)
```